# How to convert "&#67;&#111;&#110;&#118;&#101;&#114;&#116;&#84;&#101;&#120;&#116;" to ConvertText in Java?

Tags: java, xml, encoding, decoding

I want to convert `"&#67;&#111;&#110;&#118;&#101;&#114;&#116;&#84;&#101;&#120;&#116;"` to `"ConvertText"`. Its XML encoded.
Which Java class should I use for this?

We have a requirement to convert the password from plain text to XML encoded.

Comment: Did you even try your favorite search engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Commons Text's [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html) should do the trick:

```
String result = 
    StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4
    ("&#67;&#111;&#110;&#118;&#101;&#114;&#116;&#84;&#101;&#120;&#116;");
```